# Get featured image alt text wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to simple display the alt text for an image that is set in our WP library.

I tried this

```
<?php $image_id = get_post($id); ?>
<?php $image_alt = get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>
<img class="photo" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt ?>"/>
```

But it isn't displaying the alt text when I do that.  Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you been able to get the alt text?

Answer (score 0):

If the image is the featured image and you see it correctly, try this:

```
<?php
  $thumbnail_id  = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
  $thumbnail_alt = get_post_meta( $thumbnail_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
?>

<img class="photo" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" alt="<?php echo $thumbnail_alt ?>"/>
```

Let me know if you can solve it

Answer (score 0):

**THIS WORKED FOR ME**

The complete code I used to display the featured image with its alt text

```
<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?> "/>
```

For the image src

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>
```

For the alt text

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>
```

PS. Make sure you actually give your featured image some alt text in the backend.

Hope it helps someone in the future.